# "Did you pay to have the Screecher beat up?"

Tags: grammar

I'm a little bit confused with this phrase.
i understand the meaning but I can't understand it grammatically.
What is the rule in English of this part "to have the Screecher beat up?"
I thought it can be related with "have smb to do smth" but looks like it is not...

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It is US English for 'to have the Screecher beaten up?'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beat

Comment: @tchrist: are you sure you closed it for the right reason? That is, are you sure that the OP is confused about the variant past particle and not the lack of a direct object or the fact that their template has an extra "to"?

Comment: @PeterShor No, I can't say I'm sure. The construction they mention initially thinking their example was related to, like when you have somebody available  to (=who will)  take care of your kids for you while you run to the store, isn't related to the cited sentence at all. Theirs is more of a "passive causative" if you would, where the question asks whether you had parties unknown beat up the Screecher. When you have your kids driven to school because it's too far too walk, you've made somebody drive your kids there but haven't named who it is doing the driving. .

Comment: @PeterShor So perhaps the right close reason is Unclear What You're Asking. I'd really like to know what they aren't understanding because right now it's not clear, at least to me. I could re-open and let people make stabs against the unknown, or I could re-close pending clarification. Let me know what direction you think would be best here, and I'll fix it up accordingly.

Comment: @tchrist: It really should have been closed for the reason "Unclear What You're Asking." If you can just change the closing reason easily, that might be best. Otherwise, we could just ask the OP to clarify it in a comment and then reopen it once they do so.